# Can the verb "bias" not be used as a verbal in a sentence? (American English)

Tags: verbs, word-usage

Whenever I see the verb "bias" being used in a sentence, it is always used as a verbal. Can it be used as a verb (example please!)? If it cannot, is there a special name for verbs that can only be used as verbals, and are there other cases of this scenario with different verbs? For example, bias can be used as "The boy was biased" or "The biased argument was quashed." I have never seen the verb as "I will bias you after I state my argument."

Comment: Bias the grid with seven volts.

Comment: I think your preconceptions biased you against finding examples of the word being used as a plain verb.

Comment: "Can it be used as a verb (example please!)?" I wouldn't want to **bias** any full answers, but personally I am **biased** towards this verb's use in the *passive voice*.

Answer (score 2):

"Can it be used as a verb?" -- Sure, as a **transitive** verb even!

**[bias](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bias)** (Collins)

> 3. verb
>      To bias someone means to influence them in favour of a particular choice.
>      *We mustn't allow it to bias our teaching.*
>      Synonyms: influence, colour, weight, prejudice

Comment: "I will bias you after I state my argument" is grammatical, but sounds a bit, hm..., too forward-biased?

Answer (score 0):

It's a technical use, but Electrical Engineers often say "we bias the gate of the transistor with a current of...'